# Grounding Rod Requirements

Tags: grounding

I live in Mason County, in Washington State. I am installing a 100amp RV pedestal (ground mounted). I am running 4/0,4/0,20 triplex direct bury cable (not sure if going in conduit or not yet)about 160ft from the power companies transformer box that is on my property. I understand I will need a 8ft long grounding rod, but do I need to have 2 grounding rods for 100amp service? I am not sure if that only applies to 200amp service. And do I need 5/8" or 3/4" dia.
Thanks in advances
Dean

Comment: Why 4/0 for a 100A?

Comment: Having 4/0 in the ground would certainly make a heavy-up easier.

Comment: Keep in mind that if Code requires you have a disconnect out at the transformer box, then you must run 4-wire, not triplex.  The first disconnect past the meter is the service point.  You run 3-wire from the weatherhead through the meter to the first disconnect, master ground is there, then 4 wire past the disconnect.

Comment: My pedestal is my meter. It's all in one. Meter on top, 3 breakers in panel below and 50amp/30amp & 20amp outlets. I was told by the PUD3 engineer that I needed to run triplex. I am running 4/0 for possible upgrade to 200 amp at later date.  What does “4/0 ground would make a heavy up easier” mean

Comment: Harper, additional question about your comment on needing a disconnect out of the transformer. With my pedestal being meter, breakers and outlets does that have me covered going directly from my transformer and connecting to the pedestal with my triplex and not needing any other disconnect? From what I have read I should be ok.

Comment: Dean you have to @Harper-ReinstateMonica to actually draw someone's attention back.  Only askers of a question or writers of an answer are automatically notified.

Comment: @Dean you do not need a disconnect before the meter.  You also don't need a ground wire before the disconnect.  Usually the disconnect has to be pretty close to the meter, but in outdoor installations that can be farther because dirt doesn't burn. At least not anywhere east of the Rockies lol...  "Heavy-up" is slang for upgrading from a 100A service to a 200A service.  "in the ground" means already buried and in place.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I am using a James town Preassembled Rv pedestal. So from what you are saying I can go to and hookup to my pedestal with triplex? I don’t need any other boxes before pedestal between transformer and pedestal?  I was under the impression from the Pud engineer I did not. Please help clarify if you would please

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you're alright @Dean, however I'd run it by your AHJ (electrical inspector / person you pull a permit from) to be sure.  Power company guys only know their own rules (NESC) but your work is under NEC.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thanks I plan to call him Monday but I feel like I am supposed to know all this and not sure I should be bothering him with my questions. I already asked him about grounding rods and yes I need 2 as you stated. I have a few other questions for him too. You think it’s acceptable to use him as my personal adviser?

Comment: Maybe you can answer. 1. You think I should use direct bury cable even if I go in conduit?   2. Is 4/0,4/0,2/0 aluminum wire the correct size I need for 200 amp future service.. I wa reading something last night and it said that was size for copper and 2/0 was for aluminum. Confusing the hell out of me. Engineer said 4/0, 4/0, 2/0.   3. My RV pedestal does not have a main breaker, Is that ok? Just one for each outlet. Thank you

Comment: @Dean I prefer individual wires in conduit, but price it either way. Aluminum is *mandatory* in a remote location where some jackass might steal your wires, scrap copper is $3/pound these days.  As long as 200A is *your entire service*, 310.15(B)(7) gives you a favorable derate, allowing you to use 2/0 copper or **4/0 aluminum**.   If ground is called for, it would be #4 aluminum or larger. People resist that fourth ground wire because they think it'll be expensive, but  but #4 is laughably cheap compared to #4/0.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thank you. As much as I want to save money it’s more important to get it right the first time. So 4/0, 4/0, 2/0 ground  aluminum is per code? Isn’t triplex separate wires? I know I may be over thinking this and asking same question twice, sorry about that. I will ask the inspector these questions too. I hope I don’t piss him off

Comment: @Dean when there are 3 wires, the third wire is Neutral not ground.  You're gonna want neutral if you have any 120V loads.  Triplex is typically 3 wires stuck together, they don't have an outer sheath.   For conduit fill you can count them as individual wires.

Comment: Sorry, yes neutral. Triplex does not have sheathing, just each wire jacket and they are twisted together. I guess it’s just how you look at it. To me separate wires. But I know what you are saying.

Answer (score 4):

The NEC and your state codes do not reference size of service.

Washington Administrative Code [296-46B-250-053](https://apps.leg.wa.gov/WAC/default.aspx?cite=296-46B&full=true#296-46B-250) (A)(2) Resistance of rod, pipe, and plate electrodes.
(3) For rod, pipe, and plate electrodes other than those installed in accordance with the exception in subsection (2) of this section, if a ground resistance test is not performed to ensure a resistance to ground of 25 ohms or less, two or more electrodes as specified in NEC 250.52 must be installed a minimum of 6 feet apart. A temporary construction service is not required to have more than one made electrode.

NEC 250.52 says "at least 15.87 mm (5/8 in.) in diameter, unless listed."

Comment: I think in most cases you would just use dos ground rods to avoid the necessity of measuring, and also because adding one later is a real pain, especially if you already have the ground rod pounder out.